# How to get the background colour of an element in selenium RC..?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have tried the following both the codes, but did't get the solution

```
selenium.isVisible("xpath=//html/body/header/ul/li[3]/a");
selenium.getAttribute(Element@style.backgroundColor);
```

In my application there are 4 tabs, by default "Home" tab should be selected. Am plan to verify that using the background color.

How to verify the specific tab is selected or not..?

How to verify the background color of an element..?

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of attributes to find an element by. Have you tried opening (assuming this is a website) your application in Chrome, and using developer tools to view all of the controls attributes? If you were to select the frame in its entirety, you might very well find an attribute for that element that offers the hexidecimal color code applied to it.